# Why doesn't pymongo MongoDB return an exact value in find_one()?

Tags: python, mongodb, find, pymongo, data-retrieval

I want to retrieve the single value "count "from pymongo DB but it is not working. The image below shows how the data entry is setup.

[image: mongodb data entry]

Here is the call to my Database class to use the db.find_one().

CODE HERE:

```
    filters = {"email": session.get('email')}
    returns = {f'words.{today_s}.{self.length - 3}.count': 1}

    count_value = Database.find_one_return_one("users", filters, returns)

    print({f'words.{today_s}.{self.length - 3}.count':1})
    print(count_value)

@staticmethod
def find_one_return_one(collection: str, query: Dict, data: Dict) -> Dict:
    return Database.DATABASE[collection].find_one(query, data)
```

This returns an empty list of dictionaries from the correct data? I want the count value returned.

This is the projection query: {words.20220302.0.count : 1}

This is what is returned:

```
{'_id': ObjectId('621ee5065d08c44070140df0'), 'words': {'20220302': [{}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}]}}
```

What is wrong or is there a better quicker way to retrieve the count value?

Comment: You can try using the [$ projection](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/projection/positional/#mongodb-projection-proj.-) operator. You can also include the _actual_ `find_one` query you have coded.

Comment: have added the function. Still trying to figure out how to use the $ projection but thanks for trying to help :)

Comment: The _second_ parameter to the `find_one` is the "projection" (see [Project Fields to Return from a Query](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/project-fields-from-query-results/)).

Comment: Have I not already added the "projection" with my returns parameter? It is set to only return the value of count.

Comment: The variable `returns` is your projection. Does it evaluate to the correct projection? What is the correct projection (which can return the desired result)?

Comment: It does not. My projection is {words.20220302.0.count:1} but this returns {'_id': ObjectId('621ee5065d08c44070140df0'), 'words': {'20220302': [{}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}]}} and I have no idea why? In the above image I am just interested in returning the count value.

Comment: The syntax of using "words.20220302.0" - where `0` is the array index - is not valid in projection: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/project-fields-from-query-results/#project-specific-array-elements-in-the-returned-array

Answer (score 0):

The following query projection can be used to get the desired result. Note this worked with MongoDB v5.

A sample document; similar to the one in the question post:

```
{ _id: 1, words: { fld: [ { a: 1, b: 2 }, { a: 9, b: 100 } ] } }
```

The expected result is: `{ "_id" : 1, "words" : { "fld" : { "a" : 9 } } }`

The query:

```
INDEX = 1    # this is the index of the array element
query = { }
projection = { 
    'words.fld': { 
        '$arrayElemAt': [ 
            { '$map': { 'input': '$words.fld', 'in': { 'a': '$$this.a' } } }, 
            INDEX 
        ] 
    }
}

result = collection.find_one(query, projection)
print(result)
```

Comment: Awesome thank you so much. It works but have to be honest don't really understand the syntax but hopefully will. Really appreciate all the help :)

Comment: The [$arrayElemAt](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/arrayElemAt/) allows to select an array element at a particular _index_. The [$map](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/map/) allows _map_ the data, from a sub-document with multiple fields to a single field. These are Aggregation Operator Expressions, mostly used in the aggregation queries - in `$project`, `$addFields` and `$set` stages. But, starting with MongoDB v4.4 these operators can be used with the `find` method also - thus enhancing the projection functionality in `find`.

Comment: Thank you so much again. This was a huge help :)